# Add Variable If in for

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

I want to display the variable `hm` more than 0, but it always displays 0. How can I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    long long result = 1;
    int n;
    int i;
    char str[13500];
    int hm=0;  
    scanf("%d", &n);    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        result *= 9;
        sprintf(str, "%lld", result);
        printf("%c ",str[0]);
        if (str[0] == 9) {
            hm=hm+1;
        }      
    }
    printf("%d", hm); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `if (str[0] == '9') {`? `9` as a plain number will be un unprintable character.

Comment: "Hello StackOverflow!" Indeed! Do not allocate large arrays like `char str[13500];` locally, or you may get a stack overflow.

Comment: @Lundin — 13 KiB is not going to stress any desktop or server system (nor most cell phones; other embedded systems may be a different story).  At megabyte sizes, yes — caution is required.  But not at tens of kilobytes.

Comment: `char str[13500];`...why? a simple `char str[64];` would fit your need.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know what. And on some low-end microcontrollers, you have around 100 bytes of stack. Who cares, it's generic good advise not to allocate large data on the stack no matter system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str[0] == 9` looks wrong. Typically, character codes of number characters are not equal to the numbers they represent. For example, the character code for 9 is 57 (0x39) in ASCII.

To obtain character code from fixed character (character literal), surround the character with `''`. The condition should be `str[0] == '9'`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you use 'sprintf' it will store the content as a string in the buffer str.

> Composes a string with the same text that would be printed if format was used on printf, but instead of being printed, the content is stored as a C string in the
> buffer pointed by str.
> The size of the buffer should be large enough to contain the entire resulting string (see snprintf for a safer version).
> A terminating null character is automatically appended after the content.
> After the format parameter, the function expects at least as many additional arguments as needed for format.

Link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

So, just change your 'if' statement to

```
if (str[0] == '9')
```

treat the value 9 as a character by enclosing it between single quotes. Hopefully, this should work for you.